# Trading places with css animation

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

I'm working on zoom css on hover that I can't quite nail. I think this can be done with `transform scale()` but I have major flickering because of the focus is easily lost on hover. Not to mention, the effect I want to achieve is only poorly working for one image. So let me explain what I'm trying to do.

I have 2 phones overlapping each other. Ideally, the one in the background should be around `10%` smaller to achieve the effect of depth perception. When I hover over the one in the background, it should come up to the front and trade `z-index` places, zoom back up to `100%`, and make the other one reduce by `10%` (again for the percentage effect).

The same effect will happen when I hover over the one I sent back, it should come back to the front where it was before and so forth.

I will accept Javascript, but I'd rather a pure CSS solution unless jQuery/JS is a valid effort.

Here is the **HTML**

```
<div class="wrap">
  <img class="elem" src="http://www.lotusmarketingsolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/monsters-4.png" alt="" />
  <img class="elem2" src="http://www.lotusmarketingsolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/monsters-3.png" alt="" />
</div>
```

And the **CSS**

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500,700,300);
body {
  background: #202020;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.wrap {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

.wrap img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 250px;
}

.elem {
  margin-left: 130px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.elem:hover {
  zoom: 50%;
  -ms-transform: scale(2, 3);
  /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: scale(2, 3);
  /* Safari */
  transform: scale(2, 3);
}

.elem2:hover {
  zoom: 150%;
  -ms-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
  /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
  /* Safari */
  transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
}
```

And the [**CODEPEN**](http://codepen.io/LOTUSMS/pen/yePgKv)

Thanks!

Comment: What you're describing will probably require some javascript because you need to manage an event that affects another element. The only CSS way would be with adjacent sibling selectors but I think it'll be messy. I'd use js to handle the show/hide and CSS transform for the scaling.

Comment: I would accept a Javascript or jQuery solution of it makes it a smooth transition.  Sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***First* :** 
pure CSS [**JS Fiddle 1** - *updated* 2](https://jsfiddle.net/f2r7u9cg/6/), *I removed the prefixed CSS though for simplicity*

```css
    @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500,700,300);
    body {
      background: #202020;
      font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    }
    .wrap {
      width: 50%;
      margin: 0 auto;
      position: relative;
      z-index: 100;
    }
    .wrap img {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 250px;
    }
    .elem {
      margin-left: 130px;
      margin-top: 20px;
      z-index: 1000;
      transition: transform 0.3s;
    }
    .elem2 {
      z-index: 10000;
      transition: margin-left, transform 0.3s;
    }
    .elem:hover {
      zoom: 50%;
      margin-left: 500px;
      margin-top: 200px;
      transform: scale(3, 3);
      z-index: 100000;
      transition: transform 0.3s;
    }
    .elem2:hover {
      zoom: 150%;
      margin-left: -50px;
      transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
      transition: margin-left, transform 0.3s;
    }
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <img class="elem" src="http://www.lotusmarketingsolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/monsters-4.png" alt="" />
  <img class="elem2" src="http://www.lotusmarketingsolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/monsters-3.png" alt="" />
</div>
```

---

**UPDATE:**

***Second* :** using jQuery `.animate()` and `.css()` functions - *smoother animation for `.elem` phone the one behind, also more browser support*

[**JS Fiddle 2**](https://jsfiddle.net/fvrmnfrn/1/)

```
var elem = $('.elem'),
  elemW = elem.width(),
  elemH = elem.height(),
  elem2 = $('.elem2'),
  elem2W = elem2.width(),
  elem2H = elem2.height();

elem.hover(function() {
  $(this).css({'z-index': '100000'}).animate({
    width: 1.5 * elemW,
    height: 1.5 * elemH,
    marginTop: '-10',
    marginLeft: '80'
  }, 300);
}, function() {
  $(this).css({'z-index': '1000'}).animate({
    width: elemW,
    height: elemH,
    marginTop: '20',
    marginLeft: '130'
  });
});

elem2.hover(function() {
  $(this).animate({
    width: 1.5 * elem2W,
    height: 1.5 * elem2H,
    marginLeft: '-50'
  }, 300);
}, function() {
  $(this).animate({
    width: elem2W,
    height: elem2H,
    marginLeft: '0'
  });
});
```

Comment: This is not bad,  except the one that goes you the front eliminates the possibility to hover back to the other one.  Is that because of percentage in growth? Don't get me wrong.  It's a very plausible answer.  I'll pick it if nothing better.  Thanks!

Comment: Oh and I assume a fade transition would slow it down,  am I right?

Comment: I updated the fiddle already, added negative `margin-left` to the `.elem2` check it out

Comment: You welcome @LOTUSMS, I'm glad it helped, enjoy coding

Comment: @LOTUSMS, I updated my Answer with jQuery animation solution instead of CSS animation it looks smoother for `.elem` phone because the CSS one has little quirky glitch for that phone. also the jQuery one is more browser supported, back to IE6 I believe, so pick the one that suits you more.. enjoy

Comment: You know,  while I have your attention,  if you want to score another answer,  I have a question that no one has answered satisfactorily in a week.  I can't find it with my phone.  But I can send it to you later when  I'm back on my pc.

Comment: I'll do my best to get it solved if I could, but remember I won't trade my pizza for the other question though :)

Comment: Haha you got it.  It's double or nothing! Lol.  Look up "stop floating labels from resetting back to original position"

Comment: The answer in there looks ok to me, why did it not work for you? is it because you're already using the `:valid` for other purpose?

Comment: Not entirely sure to be honest but if you look at the demo,  you'll see it didn't work.  Answer makes sense tho

Comment: hmmm, something like this http://codepen.io/Mi_Creativity/pen/NxwapZ?editors=001 ??